# Here in table every TR having user and user data. Is this correct way of using of form for every user or one form for all users

Tags: html

Here in table every TR having user and user data. Is this correct way of using of form for every user or one form for all users. If I am using a form for every tr, I need to create one new table, so my alignment of each column is goes off.

[Here is the Html](http://jsfiddle.net/kdc8c/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one form for the entire table. Just assign different values to `name` attribute of `<input type="submit" />` or any other submit trigger you use.

Side note: you should avoid using `table` to markup non-table data. Obviously, you could use lists (unordered, ordered or definition lists) and divs/paragraphs to achieve the same result.

Comment: I'm talking about the tables inside `td`s.